# Wrong Confirmation Key

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, email

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.2.3 and enable email confirmation for registration. Email is sent as normal, but when I click the link, it always fails. The link is like this

> https://domain.com/customer/account/confirm/?id=10&key=1fdc9eb4eb591cfaef5878b907348587

Later on, I found out that under **customer_entity_varchar** table, Magento stores the plain text (from the password) instead of the hash string, under attribute_id 16 (confirmation). When I change this plain text to the hash string, it works.

My question is, why Magento stores the plain text whilst email the hash string?

Comment: Can you share the solution? We have the same issue. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. The culprit was Webkul Vendor Attributes extension which overwrite Magento default values and stored password and password_confirmation in plain text. Really really dangerous!

Comment: No there is no issues with webkul vendor attribute extension as we never overwrite the core default values also all those attribute are driven by magento only still have any query please raise a concern at https://webkul.com/ticket . thanks